# java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out issue

Tags: java, android

```
07-18 18:57:24.687: W/System.err(7031): java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
07-18 18:57:24.773: W/System.err(7031):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_read(NativeMethod)
07-18 18:57:24.773: W/System.err(7031):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.read(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:675)
07-18 18:57:24.773: W/System.err(7031):     at libcore.io.Streams.readSingleByte(Streams.java:41)
07-18 18:57:24.773: W/System.err(7031):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.read(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:659)
07-18 18:57:24.773: W/System.err(7031):     at libcore.io.Streams.readAsciiLine(Streams.java:201)
07-18 18:57:24.773: W/System.err(7031):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponseHeaders(HttpEngine.java:560)
07-18 18:57:24.773: W/System.err(7031):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:813)
07-18 18:57:24.773: W/System.err(7031):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:274)
07-18 18:57:24.773: W/System.err(7031):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
07-18 18:57:24.773: W/System.err(7031):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:271)
07-18 18:57:24.773: W/System.err(7031):     at com.Webservice.downloadFileAddPassword(Webservice.java:192)
07-18 18:57:24.777: W/System.err(7031):     at com.patientcontext.DocumentViewerActivity2$DocumentsShowAsyncTask.doInBackground(DocumentViewerActivity2.java:219)
07-18 18:57:24.777: W/System.err(7031):     at com.patientcontext.DocumentViewerActivity2$DocumentsShowAsyncTask.doInBackground(DocumentViewerActivity2.java:1)
07-18 18:57:24.777: W/System.err(7031):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
07-18 18:57:24.777: W/System.err(7031):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
07-18 18:57:24.777: W/System.err(7031):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
07-18 18:57:24.777: W/System.err(7031):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
07-18 18:57:24.781: W/System.err(7031):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
07-18 18:57:24.785: W/System.err(7031):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
07-18 18:57:24.785: W/System.err(7031):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Why do i get this `exception` when i try to connect to the `web-service`. I search in stack overflow for relevant errors but could not actually figure out why?

Comment: Instead of using an asyntask `AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.)` [AsyncTasks API docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Why don't you use a Service or Downloadmanager? About your exception let's see what people say :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that "com.Webservice.downloadFileAddPassword" is the package you created, and your web-service is Webservice.java. If this is true then you are having an error on line 192 of your Webservice.java. Its not that you may not be hitting the web-service, but the operation time or a process inside your web-service is timing out. Did you unit test your web-service?

I am reading in the stacktrace that you have an InputStream that you are calling which when trying to connect or read from the source, it is taking too long at which point it times out. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/SocketTimeoutException.html

So basically: webservice is using an input stream that is taking too long. I don't think I know enough to just look at your stacktrace and give any more information.

Stack Trace as a more readable format:

```
07-18 18:57:24.687: W/System.err(7031): java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out 
07-18 18:57:24.773: W/System.err(7031): at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_read(Native Method) 
07-18 18:57:24.773: W/System.err(7031): at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.read(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:675) 
07-18 18:57:24.773: W/System.err(7031): at libcore.io.Streams.readSingleByte(Streams.java:41) 
07-18 18:57:24.773: W/System.err(7031): at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.read(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:659) 
07-18 18:57:24.773: W/System.err(7031): at libcore.io.Streams.readAsciiLine(Streams.java:201) 
07-18 18:57:24.773: W/System.err(7031): at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponseHeaders(HttpEngine.java:560) 
07-18 18:57:24.773: W/System.err(7031): at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:813) 
07-18 18:57:24.773: W/System.err(7031): at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:274) 
07-18 18:57:24.773: W/System.err(7031): at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168) 
07-18 18:57:24.773: W/System.err(7031): at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:271) 
07-18 18:57:24.773: W/System.err(7031): at com.Webservice.downloadFileAddPassword(Webservice.java:192) 
07-18 18:57:24.777: W/System.err(7031): at com.patientcontext.DocumentViewerActivity2$DocumentsShowAsyncTask.doInBackground(DocumentViewerActivity2.java:219) 
07-18 18:57:24.777: W/System.err(7031): at com.patientcontext.DocumentViewerActivity2$DocumentsShowAsyncTask.doInBackground(DocumentViewerActivity2.java:1) 
07-18 18:57:24.777: W/System.err(7031): at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287) 
07-18 18:57:24.777: W/System.err(7031): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305) 
07-18 18:57:24.777: W/System.err(7031): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137) 
07-18 18:57:24.777: W/System.err(7031): at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) 
07-18 18:57:24.781: W/System.err(7031): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076) 
07-18 18:57:24.785: W/System.err(7031): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569) 
07-18 18:57:24.785: W/System.err(7031): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: No. The *SSL handshake* is timing out. See the stack trace.